# amsart.cls capitalizes the article title. How to disable it?

Tags: titles, capitalization, amsart

I am writing an article with `amsart.cls`. `amsart.cls` capitalizes the title of the article.  I looked into `amsart.cls` and found that `\MakeUppercase` is used in `\maketitle`. I tried to turn off this, but I could not. As for the author, I could turn off it. Is there any clues?

I am running TeX Live 2011 on an opensuse12.1 Linux box. `amsart.cls` is dated 2009, July.

Comment: Could you expand on 'I tried to turn off this' - what exactly did you do? Also, it's normally not a great idea to try to alter document class design where the document class is for a particular journal (or journal family): are you planning to submit your document or is it just for 'internal use'?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's always the best to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 11):

You could define an environment, which disables uppercasing for a certain scope, such as:

```
\newenvironment{nouppercase}{%
  \let\uppercase\relax%
  \renewcommand{\uppercasenonmath}[1]{}}{}
```

And in the document:

```
\begin{nouppercase}
\maketitle
\end{nouppercase}
```

After closing the environment, those temporarily disabled commands are working again, since the environment limits the scope of these redefinitions.

If you ever need to disable further uppercasing commands, such as `\MakeUppercase`, simply extend the environment.

Comment: Note: as wished we have the effect on `\MakeUppercase` already after disabling `\uppercase`, that's why I did not explicitly disable it - of course you may.

Answer (score 8):

You can temporary disable the commands `\uppercasenonmath` and/or `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\date{\today}
\author{My name}
\title{My $abc\beta$-title}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\uppercasenonmath#1{} % this disables uppercasing title
\let\MakeUppercase\relax % this disables uppercasing authors
\maketitle
\endgroup

\section{My section}
My text

\end{document}
```

Update: If you want to have the document body "clean", you can do this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\date{\today}
\author{My name}
\title{My $abc\beta$-title}

\let\origmaketitle\maketitle
\def\maketitle{
  \begingroup
  \def\uppercasenonmath##1{} % this disables uppercasing title
  \let\MakeUppercase\relax % this disables uppercasing authors
  \origmaketitle
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{My section}
My text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The command `\MakeUppercase` is hard coded so you have to redefine internal commands. Nevertheless you should think about the comment of @JosephWright.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\date{\today}
\author{My name}
\title{My title}
\makeatletter
\def\@setauthors{%
  \begingroup
  \def\thanks{\protect\thanks@warning}%
  \trivlist
  \centering\footnotesize \@topsep30\p@\relax
  \advance\@topsep by -\baselineskip
  \item\relax
  \author@andify\authors
  \def\\{\protect\linebreak}%
%  \MakeUppercase{\authors}%
  \authors%
  \ifx\@empty\contribs
  \else
    ,\penalty-3 \space \@setcontribs
    \@closetoccontribs
  \fi
  \endtrivlist
  \endgroup
}
\def\@settitle{\begin{center}%
  \baselineskip14\p@\relax
    \bfseries
%\uppercasenonmath\@title
  \@title
  \end{center}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{foo}
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a remark that this is very un-portable...

Comment: @tohecz: Of course but I don't like any big redefinition inside my document body ;-)

Comment: in that case see my updated answer ;)

Comment: @tohecz: +1 :-)