# Changing the title of an AMS article to small caps

Tags: titles, fontsize, amsart

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52118/amsart-cls-capitalizes-the-article-title-how-to-disable-it) shows how to remove the full capitalization of the title when using amsart.cls.  However, I'd still like to have small capitalization (and bold font) in the title, so that the title doesn't look smaller than the section headings.  How can we do that?

Comment: Can you provide a foundational document that we can use as a starting point for providing answers to you?

Comment: Boldface small caps? Why double emphasis?

Comment: @egreg So that the title is more prominent than the section titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the example from the linked question there are two options. Either put `\textsc{}` in the title manually:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\date{\today}
\author{My name}
\title{\textsc{My $abc\beta$-title With Caps}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\uppercasenonmath#1{} % this disables uppercasing title
\let\MakeUppercase\relax % this disables uppercasing authors
\maketitle
\endgroup

\section{My section}
My text

\end{document}
```

Or put `\scshape` in the temporary redefinition of `\uppercasenonmath`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\date{\today}
\author{My name}
\title{My $abc\beta$-title With Caps}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\def\uppercasenonmath#1{\scshape} % this disables uppercasing title
\let\MakeUppercase\relax % this disables uppercasing authors
\maketitle
\endgroup

\section{My section}
My text

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that both options require `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to use T1 font encoding, because OT1 encoding does not have the smallcaps+bold combination for the Computer Modern font.

Note also that this requires PDFLaTeX.